# Offline natural pronunciation Android library (without Google libraries)

Tags: android, speech-synthesis

I am looking for an offline natural pronunciation Android library that can speak English (preferably able to switch between US English and UK English accents).

Currently I have a pronunciation library that is only able to speak word-by-word, but the sentence spoken does not sound natural at all. One more limitation is, we cannot use Google libraries to pronounce.

I guess some libraries can learn from the grammar of a sentence / paragraph and adjust the speaking tone, for example, sentence ends with a question mark should be different from a sentence ends with a full stop.

Any recommendations?